# Creating simulated data with 2 blocks in randomized order RStudio

Tags: r, dataset, simulation

For the power analysis for my Master's Thesis I need to create a simulated dataset according to my study design.
I had this code mirroring the planned design of my study, but now my supervisor told me to change some aspects.

```
set.seed(1234)

n_participants <- 50
n_stories <- 8
  simulated_data <- data.frame(
    subj = rep(1:n_participants, each = n_stories),
    story = rep(1:n_stories, times = n_participants),
    group = rep(sample(c(-1, 1), size = n_participants, replace = TRUE), each = n_stories),
    target = rep(sample(c(-1, 1), size = n_participants * n_stories, replace = TRUE), each = 1),
    action = rep(sample(c(-1, 1), size = n_participants * n_stories, replace = TRUE), each = 1),
    interc = rep(b0,n_participants * n_stories)
  )
```

First of all, for target, I will show the participants 8 stories, but in 2 blocks of 4. The order of blocks should be randomized and in each block, there should only be either -1 or 1 for the target values.
Moreover, I need to make sure that each subject sees each value of action exactly 4 times. So each subject sees 4x -1 and 4 times 1, but in a randomized order.
I am not an R pro and therefore I seem to not be able to figure it out. Can you maybe help me with this?

For the target part, I tried this code, but then each participant only sees one type of target, which I want to avoid.

```
set.seed(123)

n_participants <- 50
n_stories <- 8

target_pattern <- rep(c(rep(c(1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1), each = 1)), length.out = n_participants)

target_pattern <- sample(target_pattern, replace = TRUE)

target_order <- rep(target_pattern, each = n_stories)

simulated_data <- data.frame(
  subj = rep(1:n_participants, each = n_stories),
  story = rep(1:n_stories, times = n_participants),
  group = rep(sample(c(-1, 1), size = n_participants, replace = TRUE), each = n_stories),
  action = rep(sample(c(-1, 1), size = n_participants * n_stories, replace = TRUE), each = 1),
  target = target_order,
  interc = rep(b0, n_participants * n_stories)
)
```

Comment: what is `b0` in the last line of data frame?

Comment: that is for the intercept of my Linear Mixed Model. I forgot to include in my question that b0 = 0.5, if that is relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust `target` so that it looks like this:

```
c(replicate(n = n_participants, rep(sample(c(-1,1)),each=4)))
```

and you can adjust `action` so that it looks like this

```
c(replicate(n = n_participants, sample(c(rep(-1,4),rep(1,4)))))
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I view the data, I can see that target values are randomized and not seen in blocks. Maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I need Block A with 4x -1 and Block B with 4x +1, and the order of these blocks is randomized for every participant.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what you mean.  See my edit